# Why is use_pyarrow in function pl.read_ipc set to default False?

Tags: python-polars

[image]

I just run this snippet and found out that the timings differ greatly.

0.00036406517028808594
vs.
0.144364595413208

Comment: Memory mapping. This difference will likely decrease with larger files as mmap comes with its own overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Pyarrow uses memory mapping by default, while polars will always read from disk.